# Convex polyhedron with five, six, or seven vertices at distinct corners of a cube

Tags: geometry, polyhedra

What are the names of the convex polyhedron with five, six, or seven vertices, where all vertices lie at distinct corners of a cube?  I'm particularly interested in the five vertex case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With five vertices, depending on which ones you choose, you can get an *oblique square pyramid*, an *oblique rectangular pyramid*, or an *irregular triangular bipyramid* with $S_3$ symmetry.

With six vertices, you can get a *right isosceles triangular prism*, an *equilateral triangular right antiprism*, or an irregular figure with $D_{2\cdot 2}$ symmetry but no name that I know of.

I don't think the seven-vertex figure has any particular name.

Neither of these names are precise enough to express the fact that the vertices are chosen among the vertices of a cube.

Comment: Well, you could call the seven-vertex one a "monotruncated cube" -- it's what you get by slicing one vertex off of a cube, as deeply as possible. (As opposed to the usual "truncated cube" which is what you get by cutting _all_ the vertices off, usually to the depth that leaves you with only regular octagon and equilateral triangular faces.) In this terminology, the unnamed six-vertex one would be a "meta bitruncated cube". (Here "meta" refers to the fact that the two vertices that are chopped off are not neighbors but are at distance 2 in the vertex network.)

Comment: The seven-vertex one is also a particular, special "tri-elevated tetrahedron," i.e. you can realize it by erecting a particular triangular pyramid on three of the four faces of a regular tetrahedron.